# Mail sending is not working on my ubuntu server. I'm trying to do it through Mailgun SMTP. What could be the problem?

Tags: ubuntu, email, smtp, mailgun

I want sent EMAIL with mailgun via SMTP. My Laravel project sent messages another hosthing, but not sent on my VDS server...
Also, my server is running on Fastpanel. Their support knows nothing.

I try the command:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.eu.mailgun.org:587 (and ports 25, 465)
```

Get error:

```
139704233522496:error:0200206E:system library:connect:Connection timed out:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
139704233522496:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=110
```